# Bash if command doesn't finish in X time?

Tags: bash, timeout

I'm trying to run something like:

```
sudo dhclient $wifi || otherFunction
```

Problem is when `dhclient` fails it just hangs instead of throwing an error.

How can I re-write the above so `dhclient` is killed and `otherFunction` gets called if `dhclient` doesn't finish in 60 seconds?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your [timeout](/questions/tagged/timeout) tag gives it all away:

```
sudo timeout 60 dhclient $wifi || otherFunction
```

An example:

```
sudo timeout 3 sleep 5 || echo finished early
```

This uses the [timeout utility](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) provided by the GNU coreutils package on Linux.

Comment: doesn't work on MacOS unfortunately

Comment: `timeout` for MacOS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21118126/451480

Comment: If you want to check specifically for `timeout` killing the command (as opposed to  the command failing for other reasons), check for exit status 124.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`timeout`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html).

```
timeout 2 sleep 1
echo $?
0

timeout 1 sleep 2
echo $?
124
```

Comment: doesn't work on MacOS unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Use the `timeout` packed as `gtimeout` with the `coreutils` port in [`brew`](https://brew.sh):

```
brew install coreutils
gtimeout --help
```

That'll work with `/usr/local/bin` in your `PATH`. If you want to use `timeout` as originally named, add `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin` to your `PATH`.